# Call forwarding in Twilio from C#

Tags: c#, twilio, call, forwarding

I am using the latest version of the Twilio Rest API .NET nuget library and I would like to forward an existing voice call. 
I did find some existing code

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Connect(string from, string to)
{
    var response = new TwilioResponse();
    response.Say("Please wait while we contact the other party");
    response.Dial("+14085993263", new { callerId = "+1234567890" });
    return TwiML(response);
}
```

But the second parameter to the Dial method seems to no longer work.
I also could not see how the above code would work given there are no Twilio authentication details.
Does anyone have any example code using the latest nuget library on how to perform call forwarding from C# (It does not have to be a web method)
I did find the Twilio example here
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/call-forwarding-csharp-mvc
but to be honest this was very little help indeed.
Thanks in advance
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The `Dial` method has updated to take all the parameters as named parameters. It's also best to create individual `Say` and `Dial` objects and use the `Append` method instead now. So now you need:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Connect(string from, string to)
{
    var response = new TwilioResponse();
    var say = new Say("Please wait while we contact the other party");
    var dial = new Dial(callerId: "+1234567890");
    var number = new Number("+14085993263");
    dial.Append(number);
    response.Append(say);
    response.Append(dial);
    return TwiML(response);
}
```

For more information, check the [examples in the TwiML documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial?code-sample=code-dial-a-phone-number-from-a-twilio-client-5&code-language=C%23&code-sdk-version=5.x).

Comment: Thanks :) How is security handled in the above scenario? e.g Do we pass in our Twilio account keys in order for this to work?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean there. TwiML works in response to webhooks from Twilio. Are you looking to [use the REST API to update live calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-modify-calls-in-progress-in-csharp)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct - I want a person to phone in to my Twilio number (Which is working) and then given a certain condition forward the in progress call to another non-Twilio number - I hope this is possible(?)

Comment: Ah, yes, then this is what you want. You can secure your endpoint by [validating that requests come from Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/security#validating-requests) and rejecting anything else.

Comment: Thanks for your help - much appreciated :)